# how to render shared components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue I am having with using shared components. My parent component looks like this..

index.js

```
import AuditData from './components/audit-data'
import StoredData from './components/stored-data'

class Audits extends PureComponent {
  render = () => {
    const {metroAudit} = this.props
    const isMonthly = metroAudit.get('isMonthly')

    return (
      <Card className='animated fadeIn'>
        <CardBody>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <h5 className='text-center'>Stored Data</h5>
                  <Card>
                    <CardBody><StoredData /></CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <h5 className='text-center'>Audit Data</h5>
                  <Card>
                    <CardBody><AuditData /></CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>}
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

The StoredData and AuditData are identical except for the data they use. both components look like this..

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep'
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Amenities from '../common/amenities'
import OwnershipType from '../common/ownership-type'

const initState = {
  noAmenities: false,
  feeSimple: true,
  checkboxes: [{
    label: '',
    value: '',
    checked: false
  }]
}

class StoredData extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    series: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.Map),
    markets: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.Map),
    sbd: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.Map)
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = initState
  }

  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    const { markets } = this.props
    const prevMarket = prevProps.markets.get('market')
    const market = markets.get('market')

    if (market !== prevMarket) this.setState(initState)
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this._setData()
  }

  _setData = () => {
    const { sbd } = this.props
    const _checkboxes = sbd.get('amenities').toJS()
    const _amenities = sbd.getIn(['data', 'amenities']).toJS()
    _checkboxes.shift()
    _checkboxes.forEach(x => {
      x.isDisabled = true
      x.checked = !!_amenities.find(y => y.value === x.value)
    })
    this.setState({checkboxes: _checkboxes})
  }

  _onOwnershipType = e => {
    const val = e.target.value
    const _state = cloneDeep(this.state)
    _state.feeSimple = val !== 'condoOwnership'
    this.setState(_state)
  }

  _onNoAmenities = () => {
    const { checkboxes } = this.state
    const _checkboxes = cloneDeep(checkboxes)
    _checkboxes.forEach(x => {
      x.checked = false
    })
    this.setState({ noAmenities: !this.state.noAmenities, checkboxes: _checkboxes })
  }

  _onAmenities = (e, i) => {
    const { checkboxes } = this.state
    const _checkboxes = cloneDeep(checkboxes)
    _checkboxes[i].checked = !_checkboxes[i].checked
    this.setState({checkboxes: _checkboxes})
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <OwnershipType
              isStoredData
              onOwnershipType={this._onOwnershipType}
              {...this.state}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Amenities
              onNoAmenities={this._onNoAmenities}
              onCheckboxes={this._onAmenities}
              {...this.state}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  series: state.series,
  markets: state.markets,
  sbd: state.sbd
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(StoredData)
```

these two components are also shared.

```
import Amenities from '../common/amenities'
import OwnershipType from '../common/ownership-type'
```

ownershipType.js

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { CardBody, Card, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import CardTitle from '../../../../../../../components/CardTitle'
import Radios from '../../../../../../../components/Radios/index'

export default class OwnershipType extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    feeSimple: PropTypes.bool,
    isStoredData: PropTypes.bool,
    onOwnershipType: PropTypes.func
  }

  render = () => {
    const {feeSimple, isStoredData, onOwnershipType} = this.props
    return (
      <Card className='animated fadeIn'>
        <CardTitle
          color='default'
          h6Class='card-h6-sbd'
          className='card-title-sbd'
          title='Ownership Type' />
        <CardBody>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Radios
                name={`${isStoredData ? 'ownershipType' : 'ownershipType-1'}`}
                label1='Fee Simple'
                label2='Condo Ownership'
                value1={'feeSimple'}
                value2={'condoOwnership'}
                checked1={feeSimple}
                checked2={!feeSimple}
                onChange={onOwnershipType}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

amenities.js

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import uuid from 'uuid'
import { CardBody, Card, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import CardTitle from '../../../../../../../components/CardTitle'
import Checkbox from '../../../../../../../components/Checkbox/index'

export default class Amenities extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    noAmenities: PropTypes.bool,
    onNoAmenities: PropTypes.func,
    onCheckboxes: PropTypes.func,
    checkboxes: PropTypes.array
  }

  render = () => {
    const {noAmenities, onNoAmenities, checkboxes, onCheckboxes} = this.props

    return (
      <Card className='animated fadeIn'>
        <CardTitle
          color='default'
          h6Class='card-h6-sbd'
          className='card-title-sbd'
          title='Amenities' />
        <CardBody>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Checkbox
                name='noAmenities'
                value='noAmenities'
                label='No Amenities'
                divClass='pull-right'
                checked={noAmenities}
                onChange={onNoAmenities}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            {checkboxes.map((item, i) => (
              <Col key={i} sm={6} md={6} lg={6}>
                <Checkbox
                  name={uuid.v4()}
                  disabled={item.isDisabled}
                  value={item.value}
                  label={item.label}
                  checked={item.checked}
                  onChange={e => onCheckboxes(e, i)}
                />
              </Col>
            ))}
          </Row>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

The issue is when I set the data. When I have both "StoredData" and "AuditData" rendered the StoredData checkboxes are not being set correctly. If you compare the "_setData" functions you will see the StoredData has dynamic data that determines if each checkbox is checked or not. However, both components are setting the checkboxes by the AuditData 
 "_setData" function. Is there a reference issue when sharing components with identical parent components? I have not run into this issue before and do not know what to search for.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "shared" component. Anyways, the nice thing about react is you don't need to worry about which component is which when troubleshooting this type of thing. just make sure that `state`, either component state or redux state is what you expect it to be. sounds like two of your components are using the same state when you want different states for the different checkboxes

Comment: Would it be possible for you to set up a plukr or something with just the minimal code? It would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: well maybe I worded it wrong. The problem is the StoredData checkboxes is being set with the AuditData checkboxes values.

Comment: @Hinrich I will see if I can put something together in a little bit. plunker the best for react?

Comment: use https://stackblitz.com/ its the fastest / easiest for react

Comment: also, I think i understood your wording.. but the thing with react is that state is state and nothing else controls checkboxes, so just check that it's different state. if its the state then that's your problem

Comment: I figured it out. I just set a timeout to load the AuditData component. working now. thanks

Comment: cool maybe you can answer your question then. its hard for me to understand how your fix relates to your code / problem

Comment: u bet. as soon as it allows me to

Comment: @texas697 you should be able to answer your question immediatly and mark it as accepted in 2 days.

Comment: @Hinrich done. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Card, CardBody } from 'reactstrap'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ReactTimeout from 'react-timeout'
import AuditData from './components/audit-data'
import StoredData from './components/stored-data'

class MetroAuditMain extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    setTimeout: PropTypes.func
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {hidden: true}
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.props.setTimeout(() => this.setState({hidden: false}), 500)
  }

  render = () => {
    const {hidden} = this.state
    return (
      <Row className='animated fadeIn'>
        <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6}>
          <Card>
            <CardBody>
              <StoredData />
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={6}>
          <Card>
            <CardBody>
              {!hidden && (
                <AuditData />
              )}
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}

export default ReactTimeout(MetroAuditMain)
```

I solved the problem by delaying the rendering of the second component. I do not understand why it is necessary to do this so if someone can comment on this that would be helpful. thanks